# exclude view from Angular "ng build" process

Tags: angular, ng-build

When we hit "ng build" while doing Angular build by default it bundles  HTML with JS and gives us one physical  JS unit file.

Is there a option in "ng build" by which i can say do not bundle the view with the JS ?

some thing like

```
ng build --exclude views
```

**Note I'm aware i can do by using webpack but do not want to explore this route for now as i have a very big project made in Angular 2 and want to quickly migrate.**

Comment: Do not know about the exclude flag but you can exclude the folder if you have all the views inside one folder, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44494434/2630817

Comment: tried but ng build still bundles them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such `flag` *(--exclude)*, however whether you gather all your views under one folder (e.g: `views`) and then in your `tsconfig.app.json` you add that folder to the `exclude` array, something like :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "exclude": [
    "views"  
  ]
}
```

And I strongly discourage this approach for architecturing reasons, even it should work.

Or try instead:

```
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.component.html",
  ]
```

Comment: I tried this but it still bundles the HTML files with the JS. Customer does not want to exclude views to be in JS due to security reasons.

Comment: And i guess this file is just for typescript compilation , bundling happens at angular and webpack level so exclusion should be at that level.

Comment: Tried ... does not exclude HTML. In that link its all TS.